# Plone 4.3 comments not displaying when using a reverse proxy

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

okay, I have my plone site outputting on port 8080 and squid caching on port 3128. I then set up apache to run a reverse proxy so that my entire site will show up as "foo.com" instead of my servername. the problem I'm running into is that when people try to visit my site through "foo.com" it doesn't show the commenting box. It's showing up through my output of squid, but when you actually type in the url it isn't there. any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you have the proper VirtualHostMonster setup, double-check all caches along the way. I doubt that commenting would look at anything more low-level than "are you logged in".

Comment: Sorry I should've been a bit more clear. The whole site shows up just fine, and when I check squid the comments are there, but on the other side of the vhm it doesn't even appear to be loading comments section. the HTML doesnt show up, but only for comments. the rest of the site loads just fine, so I'm assuming it's a problem re-writing the comment egg, which is where I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out my problem. When I set up my site I set it up as localhost:8080/example. When I was doing the reverse proxy I was pinging localhost:8080/example and then passing it as http/something.com/localroothost. Here's what it was before vs. what I finished with

```html
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3128/example/VirtualHostBase/http/foo.com:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3128/example/VirtualHostBase/http/foo.com:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/
```

and what was correct:

```html
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3128/VirtualHostBase/http/foo.com:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3128/VirtualHostBase/http/foo.com:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/
```

it's small, but for some reason the whole sit was still showing up at foo.com, minus the comments section.